# Is the server running on host "postgres_db" (10.10.0.4) and acceptinG TCP/IP connections on port 5434?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

This is docker compose for **django**

```
environment:
      SECRET_KEY: "KEY"
      DEBUG: "True"
      NAME: "NAME"
      USER: "USER"
      PASSWORD: "PASSWORD"
      HOST: "HOST"
      PORT: "5434"
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
```

This is docker compose for **postgres**

```
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_USER: ss
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ss
      PGDATA: /data/ss
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres

    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    networks:
      main_network:
        ipv4_address: 10.10.0.4
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This is my database **config data in django settings**.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME':  os.getenv('NAME'),

        'USER':  os.getenv('USER'),

        'PASSWORD':  os.getenv('PASSWORD'),

        'HOST': "postgres_db",

        'PORT':  os.getenv('PORT')
    }
}
```

I can not find my mistake. I spent 4-5 hours but no success.

still I get this error **Is the server running on host "postgres_db" (10.10.0.4) and acceptinG TCP/IP connections on port 5434?** when I write docker compose up

Comment: Is the postgres container working normally? Did you check the status of postgres service in its container?

Comment: @Jarvis Yes it works normally, I can connect if I write 127.0.0.1 in my settings file.But in docker it does not work.

Comment: Why have you added the networks configuration in postgres's Dockerfile?

Comment: @Jarvis because I want to connect from django in docker

Comment: Can't you use the docker container's name directly running on localhost? Why have you specified `10.10.0.4` explicitly?

Comment: @Jarvis I changed  but again did not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226423/discussion-between-elvin-jafarov-and-jarvis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I deleted all containers,volumes and images then worked.

Answer (score 0):

It usually runs on port '5432', by default.